# How do I correctly constrain to related class type when using a generic method?

Tags: c#, generics, methods, generic-type-parameters

I have two base classes `BaseObject` and `BaseObjectSettings`.  The first defines the object behaviour and the second defines the state of the class (useful for serialisation).

If I want to create a derived BaseObject class with specific settings then I can use a method with a generic type constraint.

```
public void CreateBaseObjectInstance<T>(BaseObjectSettings baseObjectSettings) where T : BaseObject
{
    var instance = pool.GetInstance<T>();
    instance.Settings = baseObjectSettings;
    scene.Add(instance);
}
```

The problem I am facing is that while I can constrain the generic type to BaseClass I can't constrain the BaseClassSettings to the relevant derived BaseClass.  This means that I can do things like

```
CreateBaseObjectInstance<Banana>(new AppleSettings());
```

which seems a bit terrible.

What are my options given that I am currently constrained to both creating and initialising the object in the same method before adding it to the scene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to have all your settings classes inherit from a *generic* base class. The generic base class could then inherit from `BaseObjectSettings`. The generic type parameter indicates what kind of object this settings class is for.

For example, for your `AppleSettings`,

```
class AppleSettings: ObjectSettings<Apple> {
    ...
}

abstract class ObjectSettings<T>: BaseObjectSettings where T: BaseObject {}
```

Now, you can change `CreateBaseObjectInstance` to accept an instance of `ObjectSettings<T>` instead:

```
public void CreateBaseObjectInstance<T>(ObjectSettings<T> objectSettings) where T : BaseObject
{
    var instance = pool.GetInstance<T>();
    instance.Settings = objectSettings;
    scene.Add(instance);
}
```

If you pass `Banana` as `T`, it would expect `ObjectSettings<Banana>`, preventing you from giving it `AppleSettings`, which is `ObjectSettings<Apple>`.

Comment: Got any links etc for reading up on that pattern?  On another question it was suggested to me to use class Apple : Fruit<Apple> and that syntax (where it appears sort of self-referencing) throws me off.  I would like to read some authoritative explorations of that pattern, if they're out there.

Comment: @Aerik I think this is the "curiously recurring template pattern". Just google that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the logic here as things are missing, but from the code provided you can probably write:

```
public void CreateBaseObjectInstance<TBase, TSettings>(TSettings baseObjectSettings)
where TBase : BaseObject 
where TSettings : BaseObjectSettings
```

Used like that:

```
CreateBaseObjectInstance<Banana, AppleSettings>(new AppleSettings());
```

Can be improved to:

```
public void CreateBaseObjectInstance<TBase, TSettings>(TSettings baseObjectSettings)
where TBase : BaseObject 
where TSettings : BaseObjectSettings, new()
{
  if ( baseObjectSettings == null ) baseObjectSettings = new TSettings();
  ...
}

CreateBaseObjectInstance<Banana, AppleSettings>();
```

But if there is a strong coupling between entity and settings, you should redesign to define dependency with an association using a thing that can also be similar to @Sweeper's and @Moho's answers:

[Association, Composition and Aggregation in C#](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Association-Composition-and-Aggregation-in-Chash)

[Understanding the Aggregation, Association, Composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37915501/)

[Generics in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/generics/)

[Generic classes and methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a generic interface or base class that where you define the settings type:

```
public class BaseObject<TSettings>
{
    public TSettings Settings { get; set; }
}
```

Then your method will require two generic arguments - one for the actual object to create `TObject` and one for method's argument for the settings `TSettings`.  You then constrain `TObject` to an implementation of the implemented interface or base class/derivation thereof, using generic argument `TSettings` as the constraint's type's generic argument

```
public void CreateBaseObjectInstance<TObject, TSettings>(
    TSettings settings
)
    where TObject : BaseObject<TSettings>
{
    ...
}
```

Example (using above `BaseObject` implementation):

```
public class MyObjectSettings
{
    ...
}

public class MyObject : BaseObject<MyObjectSettigns>
{
}
```

Method call:

```
var settings = new MyObjectSettings(){ ... };

CreateBaseObjectInstance<MyObject>( settings );  // second generic argument should be inferred
```