# How to automatically generate a series of many instances of a class with as little code as possible?

Tags: c#, list, class, range, instantiation

I have a class Person, that has some fields:

```
public class Person()
{
  private string _name;
  private bool _sex;
  private enum _race; 
}
```

Also I have some methods and constructors that generate values for these fields. They are not relevant really, so i omitted them.

For example, lets assume I need to instantiate this class 587 times.
Manually I'd do it like this:

```
//pXXXX - is a name of each class, that would serve as an ID.
Person p0001 = new Person();
Person p0002 = new Person();

Person p0587 = new Person();
```

Obviously, it's a very inefficient way to do so. So I decided that I'd use some method to generate a list.

`List<Person> listOfPeople = new List<Person>();`

And have this method insert each out of 587 instances  into this list.
The problem is - I don't know how to generate all these instances automatically, giving them unique names.

Comment: Why would you need that many variables with unique names? Or do you need to generate unique value for the property ```_name```?

Comment: If they are in an indexed list, you don't need unique names; refer to them as `listOfPeople[i]`

Comment: As a general rule, if you find yourself writing variable names which contain indexes (like your `p...` variables with an index suffix), consider putting them in a container like an array or a list. If you index them with something that is not integer (e.g., a name) consider a dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean unique `variable name` by the unique name, the following code is the cleanest way to achieve that.

```
List<Person> listOfPeople = new List<Person>();
for (int i = 0; i < 587; i++) 
{
    listOfPeople.Add(new Person());
}
```

Then you can call specific object by using the index number as such,

```
listOfPeople[0];
```

On the other hand, if you want to fill _name field with a unique data for every instance of object,

```
List<Person> listOfPeople = new List<Person>();
for (int i = 0; i < 587; i++) 
{
    var person = new Person()
    {
        _name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
    }
    listOfPeople.Add(person);
}
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: @Mureinik thanks for the heads up, I hope the answer covers requirements now.

Comment: @OhWelp yes, now it seems to address that point. I'll remove my comment.

Comment: *Then you can call specific object by using the index number as such* - _name is private

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes _name field should be made public or Person class should implement a public getter property for the private fields. On the other hand, it's not the related to the asked question but I still removed ._name part to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Having for example such enumerations:

```
public enum Gender
{
  Femele,
  Male,
  ...
}

public enum Ethnic
{
  African,
  Asian, 
  European,
  ...
}
```

And this class:

```
public class Person
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public Gender Gender { get; set; }
  public Ethnic Ethnic { get; set; }
}
```

You can use this loop:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

int peopleCount = 587;

List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

foreach ( var index in Enumerable.Range(1, peopleCount) )
  people.Add(new Person());
```

Select can also be used as exposed by @lrpe.

The number can be set as a const or a static or an instance member that can be readonly or modifiable:

```
public const int PeopleCount = 587;

static public int PeopleCount { get; } = 587;

public int PeopleCount { get; set; } = 587;
```

The same for the object:

```
private readonly List<Person> People = new List<Person>();
```

Here it is a composite:

[Understanding the Aggregation, Association, Composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37915501/)

[What is the difference between association, aggregation and composition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885937/)

Initializing members of a person depend on more details about your design and goal: you will probably set them via a user window or from a data file.

A default name can be assigned in the loop:

```
foreach ( var index in Enumerable.Range(1, PeopleCount) )
    People.Add(new Person { Name = $"Person {index}" });
```

Or using Select:

```
People.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, PeopleCount)
                          .Select(index => new Person { Name = $"Person {index}" }));

People = Enumerable.Range(1, PeopleCount)
                   .Select(index => new Person { Name = $"Person {index}" })
                   .ToList();
```

Perhaps you may prefer or want to use in addition to name an ID:

```
public class Person
{
  public Guid Id { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public Gender Gender { get; set; }
  public Ethnic Ethnic { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

If setters are not needed set them private or init only, and also use real fields if needed like in your original code.

[How do you like your primary keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404040/)

[How generate unique Integers based on GUIDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920696/)

[Can using Ticks of DateTime.Now can generate duplicates unique identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65550289/)

[Guid vs INT - Which is better as a primary key?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/264/guid-vs-int-which-is-better-as-a-primary-key)

[Universally unique identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)

Answer (score 0):

> Giving them unique names

You'll have to generate them. For example:

```
var listOfPeople = new List<Person>();

for (int i = 0; i < 587; i++) 
{
    listOfPeople.Add(new Person() {
      Name = "Sir " + Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
    });
}
```

Upgrade the private field in Person to be a public property

You can get as fancy as you like with the name generator, including using services/libraries that generate real sounding fake data

Don't get hung up on trying to generate variable names; they get lost during compilation anyway so a variable name is only meaningful to you as a developer and only when the program is being written. If there was a way to generate random variable names they wouldn't actually be that usable to you as a developer.

In general when you want to "programmatically generate a variable name" you use an array or list:

```
Person[] p = new Person[10]();

p[7] = new Person...
```

The `p` is the fixed part of the variable name. The index `[7]` is the changeable part. As a whole it refers to a single instance of a person, like `Person p7 = new Person...` would.. it's just that you can use eg an integer variable in place of the fixed 7 with an array, but you can't with one where the 7 is baked into the variable name from the get go..